# Searching for an index of max element in a "list of lists" using only specific axis

Tags: python, list, numpy

I am new to Python, so please help.

I need to find the max element and it's index in a two-dimensinal list, but I need to search only one column. It is better to explain using example:

Initial list of lists:

`a = [[1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 2.0], [4.0, 4.0], [8.0, 1.0]]`

I need to search the position x in a, where a[x][1] will be max in a[x][1]. So I don't need to search for a max in a "specified column".

The output must give x = 2, because
`a[2][1] == 4`

I don't want to scan all the list in a cycle manually, I am searching for the elegant way in Python.

What approach should I use?

I have tried to use

```
max = max(a)
print(max)
```

but it gives a [8.0, 1.0] output - the element of a list with the maximum element inside.

OR for example,

```
max2 = np.max(a, axis=1)
max2_indexes = np.argmax(a, axis=1)
print(max2)
print(max2_indexes)
```

that outputs for provided data

[4. 2. 1. 8.]
[0 0 0 0]

I am suggesting to use Numpy axis=0 parameter but maybe there is a more naive way of doing this without cycles?

```
max2_indexes = np.argmax(a, axis=0)
```

In this case I have a right answer `[3 2]`, but maybe it's a wrong approach?

(The real list is very large - about 100000 of "small lists")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [2]: a = [[1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 2.0], [4.0, 4.0], [8.0, 1.0]]
```

A "transpose" of such a nested list is:

```
In [3]: a1 = list(zip(*a))    
In [4]: a1
Out[4]: [(1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 8.0), (1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 1.0)]
```

And from that you can easily get the max of "2nd column":

```
In [5]: a1[1]
Out[5]: (1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 1.0)    
In [6]: max(a1[1])
Out[6]: 4.0
```

or we can just get the 2nd column with a simple list comprehension:

```
In [13]: max([i[1] for i in a])
Out[13]: 4.0
```

`numpy` makes treating rows and columns like this easier - but at the expense of converting the list to array:

```
In [7]: A= np.array(a)    
In [8]: A.max(axis=0)
Out[8]: array([8., 4.])
```

and it makes finding the index easier:

```
In [9]: A.argmax(axis=0)
Out[9]: array([3, 2], dtype=int64)
```

You can select the 2nd column either before or after the `argmax`:

```
In [10]: A.argmax(axis=0)[1]
Out[10]: 2
In [11]: A[:,1].argmax()
Out[11]: 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think to use NumPy is elegant way and it must be faster than converting to list and transposing it?

Comment: It depends on what you are starting with.  The `a` you show is a list.  Often sticking with lists is faster.  Converting a list to array is a non-trivial operation.  `list(arr)` is also relatively slow, since it is essentially `[i for i in arr]`.  But `arr.tolist()` is quite fast - it is an array compiled method.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the maximum value in a nested list by using max function :

```
max(a,key = lambda x:x[1])

#output
[4.0, 4.0]
```

Now, when you have the maximum value you can find the index by using enumerate and looping:

```
for x,y in enumerate(a):
    if y==max(a,key = lambda x:x[1]):
        print(x)

#output
2
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! But as I mentioned - it's convenient not to use the cycles for this, that's why I have tried NumPy argmax. But I thought that there is more elegant way doing this.